# RediSearch sort by numeric field then by distance when using geofilter

Tags: redis, redisearch

How can I sort results, first by some numeric field (for example by price) then by distance when using GEOFILTER in RediSearch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [FT.SEARCH](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Commands/#ftsearch) command does not support multiple fields with SORTBY.

However you can use the [FT.AGGREGATE](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Commands/#ftaggregate) command and the [geodistance](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Aggregations/#list_of_geo_apply_functions) function for this.

Here is an example using REDIS-CLI:

```
HSET doc1 price 9.99 location "-122.41,37.77"
(integer) 0
HSET doc2 price 19.99 location "-122.40,37.78"
(integer) 0
HSET doc3 price 19.99 location "-122.42,37.79"
(integer) 0
FT.CREATE idx SCHEMA price NUMERIC SORTABLE location GEO SORTABLE
OK
FT.AGGREGATE idx "@price:[0 100]" APPLY 'geodistance(@location, "-122.39,37.78")' AS dist SORTBY 4 @price DESC @dist ASC
1) (integer) 3
2) 1) "location"
   2) "-122.40,37.78"
   3) "dist"
   4) "879.1"
   5) "price"
   6) "19.99"
3) 1) "location"
   2) "-122.42,37.79"
   3) "dist"
   4) "2862.08"
   5) "price"
   6) "19.99"
4) 1) "location"
   2) "-122.41,37.77"
   3) "dist"
   4) "2080.58"
   5) "price"
   6) "9.99"
```

Comment: I'm unable to make GEO field sortable using NRediSearch. I have to add `LOAD 1 @location` to the query, to get any results.